# Why messaging.getToken() cannot be used in service worker scope

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

### Environment

- Operating System version: MacOS High Sierra 10.13
- Firebase SDK version: 4.9.0
- Firebase Product: messaging

### Problem

According to the trace I get when I call `messaging.getToken()` in service worker scope, the root of the error lies in a call to `window.btoa()` in which `window` is, obviously, not defined. The culprit can be found in a helper function in [array-buffer-to-base64.ts](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/fcc77c2dccb9780450def9d511540e64991f3723/packages/messaging/src/helpers/array-buffer-to-base64.ts#L18) of Firebase SDK:

```js
function toBase64(arrayBuffer) {
    const uint8Version = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    return window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uint8Version));
}
```

Beyond resorting to `btoa`, is there any technical reason for `messaging.getToken()` not being able to be used in service worker scope?

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Ensure you are in service worker scope
2. Setup Firebase with `firebase.initializeApp()`
3. Retrieve messaging instance: `const messaging = firebase.messaging()`
4. Call `messaging.getToken()`

Comment: This sounds like it should include a javascript tag. Also, without seeing your code and where the error actually appears, we would be guessing. i.e. where does window.btoa() come into play and why is window not defined? You will need https and to register your serviceWorker as well. Was that done? (hint - CODE is really important to include when asking questions). If you haven't seen this, read over [Service Workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#you_need_https)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jay. What do you mean by "include a javascript tag"? I'm managing dependencies with npm and injecting my code in the service worker with [`importScripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts). Service workers have no browsing context, so `window` is naturally undefined and, yes, I have successfully registered my service worker. Anyhow, I've just updated my post and added repro steps.

Comment: You included the *firebase* and *firebase-cloud-messaging* tags in your question. It's usually a good idea to include your platform as well so I was suggesting to add a Javascript tag. Please include code in your question as links break and change which would invalidate the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, I found out that if I define the following

```js
const btoaCopy = self.btoa; // self is ServiceWorkerGlobalScope

self.window = {
    btoa: (...args) => btoaCopy.call(self, ...args)
};
```

before calling `messaging.getToken()`, no error is thrown and the returned token string seems to be exactly the same as the one retrieved in the client. Therefore, this leads me to think it is a potential bug. I'm going to report it in GitHub for feedback.